# Program crashes when I insert larger numbers

Tags: c

I'm solving a problem online. I have the code written and it works most of the time, except for when I enter numbers which are larger than usual (1000 to 2000). When I do so the program crashes and returns a very small negative number.
What can be the cause of this?

[Here](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=991) is the link to the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int z, T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for (z = 0; z < T; z++) {
        int i, j, N, P;
        scanf("%d%d", &N, &P);
        int days[3651] = { 0 };
        int hartal[10];
        int count = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < P; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &hartal[i]);
        }

        for (i = 1; i < N + 1; i++) {
            days[6] = 2;
            days[6 + (i * 7)] = 2;
            days[7] = 2;
            days[7 + (i * 7)] = 2;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < P; i++) {
            int a = hartal[i];
            for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
                if (j % a == 0 && days[j] != 2) {
                    days[j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 1; i < N + 1; i++) {
            if (days[i] == 1) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        printf("%\n%d\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged "c++"? There's nothing C++ about it, it's plain C and a modern C++ solution would look quite different.

Comment: The size of `days` is hard coded to `3651`, and expressions like `days[7+(i*7)]` are maybe out of bound. Same for `hartal`.

Comment: Read the question again *carefully* - at least one of your arrays is not big enough.

Comment: The behavior you describe looks like integer overflow.

Comment: "The next line contains another integer P (1 ≤ P ≤ 100)" but you specify that `hartal` is only size 10?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample `input` where it has failed?

Answer (score 1):

```
days[6+(i*7)] = 2;
```

That line of the code can be an out of bounds access. (aka you would be trying to access an index outside of the array days' bounds.) when **i > 520**.